# Blender snap option through icon

Tags: modifiers, objects, interface, transforms

[image: 3Ds max snap Option.]

This is the Snap rotation option in 3ds max, can any one help me out on this option in blender, I dont know whether this option is there or not in blender, the good part in this option is if i set the rotation degree to 90, when i rotate the object through rotation tool it will rotate in to 90 degree.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this buttons, which are for snapping generally:
[image]

If you want to have a snap during rotation, press ctrl while rotating (this also applies for scaling and moving.
Or you could just type `r z 180` on your keyboard. This would rotate your selection on the z axis on 180°.

Edit:

If you enable snapping and activate the right button (on the first picture) everything will snap to grid. You then can press N to open the right side panel and there you will find some settings for the grid.

[image]